# Gulp browserSync Firefox Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, gulp, gulp-browser-sync

How do we define the browser for gulp browserSync. I am on ubuntu 16.04, I have chrome, firefox and firefox developer edition installed on my machine and I want gulp browserSync to open firefox developer edition. How can I do that? Here is my configuration :

```
function startBrowserSync() {
    options = {
        browser: 'FirefoxDeveloperEdition',
        proxy: 'localhost:' + port,
        port: 3000,
        files: [],
        ghostMode: {
            clicks: true,
            location: false,
            forms: true,
            scroll: true
        },
        injectChanges: true,
        logFileChanges: true,
        logLevel: 'debug',
        logPrefix: 'gulp-patterns',
        notify: true,
        reloadDelay: 0 
    };
    browserSync(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by typing firefox, then hitting tab on the command line. It auto completed to firefox-developer. So add this line and it should work fine.

browser: 'firefox-developer',

Answer (score -1):

I just achieved it with the option :

```
browser: "firefox_dev"
```

But it might depends of how you installed firefox developer edition on your system, and how this one runs firefox developer edition.

For more precision, if I type 'firefox_dev' in the commande line, a new firefox developer edition opens.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it doesn't work for me. When I type "firefox_dev" in commande line, nothing happens, so I tried to make an alias "firefox_dev" that would launch firefox developer edition but even with this alias, it doesn't work :(